# Eigenvalue and eigenfunction of Hamiltonian on interval $[0,1]$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, operators, eigenvalue

I am seeking the minimum eigenvalue and the eigenfunction of the following Hamiltonian on interval $[0,1]$;

$$\hat{P}^2+ c \hat{Q}^{-1} + c (I-\hat{Q})^{-1}$$

where $c $ is an arbitrary positive constant.
$\hat{P} $ is the momentum operator and $\hat{Q}$ is the position operator.

Comment: hi @Masahito Hayashi. Welcome to PSE. Can you please let readers know what system this Hamiltonian represents and provide more context? Thanks.

Comment: Here are two potential walls at x=0,1 in 1-dim.  Very simple model.

Comment: What is the system you are studying?

Comment: I am sorry that I am considering this problem in a mathematical viewpoint. But, I think that this Hamiltonian is very natural.

Comment: In what way do you think this is very natural?

Comment: This is because c Q^{-1} and c(I-Q)^{-1} can be regarded as usual potential functions.

Comment: You  may display the singularity structure of your potential  by shifting *x=y+1/2* : you may rewrite it as $c(1/4-y^2)^{-1}$.

Comment: You might brush up on [background](https://doi.org/10.1119/1.2165248)